# Can anyone help me with this crontab?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

We want to download the stock price of Tesla every day, using the package "quantmod" in R. We managed to write the function that downloads the last available stock and store it in a database in SQL: indeed, if we run the function manually, we can see the table with the stock price of today. However, if we let it run alone with crontab, it doesn't work: we set it up on the 14th, and as of today, it only downloaded the price of the 18th. This is how we set up the crontab:

```
# m h dom mon dow user1 command

59 23 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/Rscript...
```

Anyone? I'm sure it's a stupid mistake but it doesn't work.

Comment: The common problem with cron is that the user environment is not loaded when the command is run. Inside the script, ensure that all paths are absolute, and maybe load the user env variables if necessary.

Comment: how do i check?

Comment: The first step in diagnosing such issues is to check the emails and/or logs for cron ... Since you're *- thankfully -* not discarding any output you should be able to find out if/how it's failing.

Comment: i'm not receiving any email

Comment: And the logs? What do they say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule cron jobs with package [`cronR`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=cronR).

```
library(cronR)

f <- "/home/project/daily.R"
cmd <- cron_rscript(f)
cmd <- cron_add(
  command = cmd,
  frequency = "59 23 * * 1-5"
)
```